# Selenium & Node.js: Switching to Created Tab dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

In the case of 1 tab, the newest tab will always be the last tab.
Same applies if it is the last tab that is used to open a new tab.
The following code will switch to last tab.

**EDIT** : Thanks to @JimEvans
In most answers on SO, you will find hardcoded indexes for windows. Like below:

```js
return await driver.wait(async function () {
    return await driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(async function (handles) {
       // var isHandleCount2 = (handles.length == 2);
        if (handles.length > 1) {
            return driver.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);
        }
        return false;
    });
}).then(function () {
    // Now do some stuff in new tab

});
```

What about the case where we have 5 tabs, and active tab 3 opens a new tab and the new tab is launched between tab 3 and tab 4.

How do we get the index of the newly created tab dynamically, without hardcoding its index, as in most examples on SO?

Comment: Your assumption that if `n` tabs/windows are opened, then in the list of handles returned by `getAllWindowHandles`, the last tab/window opened will be the `nth` window (index = length - 1) is incorrect. The order of window handles returned is not guaranteed to be in any order, and this is codified by the W3C WebDriver Specification. If experience has demonstrated otherwise, you’re either seeing an artifact of the WebDriver implementation (i.e. chromedriver), or you’ve just gotten lucky so far.

Comment: @JimEvans you missed the point of my introduction, and the question. i am not providing an answer.

Comment: No, I didn’t miss the point at all. Your code example assumes “last tab == last index in the list.” This is not necessarily true. The right approach is to get the list of active window handles before triggering the action that causes the new window to be displayed, trigger the action to open the new window, get the list of handles again, and compare the lists. The new handle in the second list is the newly opened one, no matter where it appears in the list. This approach is correct regardless of language, but I do not have a JavaScript example to easily share.

Comment: I support what @JimEvans says.

Comment: Thanks @JimEvans, your comment is what is was expecting. Wish i could see a working source code in Javascipt and Selenium

Answer (score 1):

Yeah people do things all the time that they don't completely understand and don't realize that the code doesn't always work as they expect.

As Jim pointed out, the order of the window handles (tabs) in the returned array from `.getAllWindowHandles()` is not guaranteed. You can call `.getAllWindowHandles()`, store that list as `before`, create your new tab, call `.getAllWindowHandles()` again and store that new list as `after`, and then compare the two and find the handle in the new list that doesn't exist in the old list... that's the handle of your newly created tab.

I don't do JS but you can use the `.filter()` function to do this comparison.

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(value) {
        return (b.indexOf(value) === -1);
    });
}

console.log(array_diff(["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b"]));
```

This returns `["c"]`.

I can imagine you doing something like

```
before = driver.getAllWindowHandles();
// do something that creates a new window/tab
// might need to wait for the new window to be created
after = driver.getAllWindowHandles();
handle = array_diff(after, before);
driver.switchTo().window(handle);
```

Comment: you response is pregnant with a wonderful approache. I have to test this. One question. What if the current tab is closed and you have to move back to the tab that created it?

Comment: You would still have the handle `before` which points to the original tab. You would just add `driver.switchTo().window(before);` when you want to switch back to it.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.