# Disable tabs opened in selenium (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im using the selenium webdriver for node.js and im also loading an extension, loading the extension works fine but when I start my project it goes to the page I want then instantly the extension opens a new tab (Thank you for adding this extension bla bla bla), Im wondering if theres a way to disable tabs that are not opened by myself, ive tried this:

```
await driver.get('https://mywebsite.com') //open my initial site
await driver.sleep(1000) //give time for the extension site to open
driver.switchTo(await driver.getAllWindowHandles()[1]) //switch to extension site
await driver.close()
driver.switchTo(await driver.getAllWindowHandles()[0]) //switch back to the main site
//rest of my code
```

Unfortunately this just does not seem to work, any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to disable tabs not opened by your script. As long as you don't change window handles, the driver will still be on the original tab. You can proceed with the script from there, ignoring the other opened tabs.

I think the main issue I see with your code is that you are passing parameters to `.switchTo()` instead of `.window()`. It should be `driver.switchTo().window(handle);`.

If you want to find the new window to close it, I wrote that code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615290/2386774). All you need to do is to add the `.close()` line after that code and switch back to the original handle, which you already have in your current code (after fixing with my feedback above).

Another approach is heavily based on the [selenium.dev docs](https://www.selenium.dev/docs/site/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#switching-windows-or-tabs):

```
// Open the initial site
await driver.get('https://mywebsite.com')

// Store the ID of the original window
const originalWindow = await driver.getWindowHandle();

// Wait for the new window or tab
await driver.wait(async () => (await driver.getAllWindowHandles()).length === 2, 10000);

// Loop through until we find a new window handle
const windows = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
windows.forEach(async handle => {
  if (handle !== originalWindow) {
    await driver.switchTo().window(handle);
  }
});

await driver.close()
await driver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);
// Rest of the code
```